# Отвалился звук на Linux Parrot

Tags: linux, аудио, alsa, parrot

После установки KDE отвалился звук. Вначале был фиктивный выход, но со временем он пропал и остались звуковые адаптеры от hdmi. Пытался починить звук своими ручками, ничего не вышло. Alsamixer видит мою звуковую карту, а ось не видит через параметры звука. Конфига Alsa тоже нет. В чем беда?

Comment: В параметрах звука это не то как ось видит, а то как ваш WM (Windows manager - Gnome/KDE etc). **lspci | grep -i aud** что выдает?

Comment: 00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
01:05.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4200 Series]